# Passing data on click in RecyclerView.Adapter

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` on my fragment that shows certain files i've loaded from an FTP Server.
I'm trying to set an `onClickListener` for each item, so when it will be clicked, a `DialogFragment` will be shown, in which the user will be able to choose whether to download or open the file.
**My problem is:**
I need to send to my dialog 2 things:

1. The target fragment, which will download/open the file after the user chooses what to do. This can be easily dont with `setTargetFragment()`, the only problem is I dont have access to the fragment within my `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`.
2. The name of the file to be downloaded/opened. So that the dialog will send that to the target fragment. The problem here is that I dont have access to the dataset within the `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` since its static and my dataset is not.

**Why on ViewHolder**
If there's a better place to do that, I'd be happy to hear. The reason I'm trying to that within my `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` is that it has access to the position (the item that was clicked). I've thought about doing that on `onBindViewHolder()`, but there I have access to the dataset BUT NOT to the position.

**Code of my Adapter:**

```
public class FilesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FilesAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    public final String TAG = "FILES_ADAPTER";
    private FTPFile[] dataset;

    //some methods and stuff...

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public final String TAG = "FILES_VH";
        private final TextView nameTextView;
        private final TextView infoTextView;
        private final ImageView imageView;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            // Define click listener for the ViewHolder's View.
            v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Element " + getPosition() + " clicked.");
                    //here i want to open the dialog fragment and start downloading/openning

                }
            });
            nameTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.fileNameTextView);
            infoTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.fileInfoTextView);
            imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.fileImageView);
        }

        public TextView getNameTextView() {
            return nameTextView;
        }

        public ImageView getImageView() {
            return imageView;
        }

        public TextView getInfoTextView() {
            return infoTextView;
        }
    }

}
```

Help will be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: in `onClick(View v)` you can call `v.getLayoutParams()` and cast the result to `RecyclerView.LayoutParams`

Comment: How's that suppose to help me?

Comment: checked the docs of class i'm talking about ?

Comment: yes, but it only helps to get the position by getAdapterPosition(), i still dont have any access to the actual data.

Comment: then setup your `OnClickListener` inside `onCreateViewHolder`, `onCreateViewHolder` is a part of your `Adapter` where you have access to your data model, also in Adapter you can call `RecyclerView#getChildAdapterPosition` / `RecyclerView#getChildLayoutPosition` so no need of using `LayoutParams`

Comment: I've managed to do this in some other way, but thank you anyway for you effort :)

Comment: so share your solution then...

Comment: Was working on it :)

Answer (score 4):

So I've found a solution for this, I created a custom `OnClickListener` on `onBindViewHolder()` with the matching parameters, and set it to the `ViewHolder`:
**ViewHolder:**

```
 public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private final TextView nameTextView;
        private final TextView infoTextView;
        private final ImageView imageView;
        public final String TAG = "FILES_VH";
        private View v;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            this.v = v;
            nameTextView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.fileNameTextView);
            infoTextView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.fileInfoTextView);
            imageView = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.fileImageView);
        }

        public void setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener listener){
            v.setOnClickListener(listener);
        }

}
```

**My custom Listener:**

```
private class downloadOnClickListener implements View.OnClickListener{
        RemoteFilesFragment fragment;
        String file;

        public downloadOnClickListener(RemoteFilesFragment fragment, String file){
            this.file = file;
            this.fragment = fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "File " + file + " clicked.");
            DownloadDialog dialog = DownloadDialog.newInstance(file);
            dialog.setTargetFragment(fragment, 1);
            Log.e(TAG, fragment == null ? "fragment null" : "fragment not null");
            FragmentManager fm = fragment.getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            dialog.show(fm, "Download");
        }
    }
```

**and on onBindViewHolder() add this code:**

```
holder.setOnClickListener(new downloadOnClickListener(fragment, dataset[position].getName()));
```